# Draw Icon on canvas image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have the following code that load image into my canvas:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="900"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

  };
  imageObj.src = 'Map.png';

  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
  var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);  
</script>
```

I know how to draw a dot, But I want to know how to draw my marker (example green icon) on x,y on the image, how can i do that?

I have image with my marker, I just want to draw my image marker on my image map.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: I just want to add to my code function that draw marker on my loaded picture

Comment: You've posted the code. What does it do?

Comment: I have exist image, i want to be able to draw on my loaded image another image/icon

Comment: Doesn't the posted code do what you want? If not, what's the exact problem you have with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the same for your marker what you're doing for your map:

```
...
var markerObj = new Image();

markerObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(markerObj, x, y);
};
markerObj.src = 'marker.png';
...
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/puyobosasa/edit?js,output)

Comment: `markerObj.style['z-index'] = "1";` to make the marker show above the map.